# How to measure a quantum circuit's execution time on a real IBM device?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I am executing a quantum circuit on an IBM quantum device and I need to start a timer as soon as the job in the queue starts running. I have already used:

```
result = job.result() 
execution_time = result.time_taken
```

but in this particular case what I need is more like a "signal", like a variable that is switched on as soon as the queue is over and causes the timer to start. I tried using the job status but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

`result.time_taken` *is* the execution time. There is also `job.time_per_step()` that gives you the timestamps of each step of the job's life cycle.

If you're looking to set some variable locally in your program, the best you can do is probably use job status. `job.wait_for_final_state()` supports a callback function that you can use to set the variable when status changes.

Comment: Do these functions provide any more information than is given in the run details on the IBMQ webpage?

Comment: If by more information you meant more fine grained break down of the process (e.g. each validation step), then no.